# UITableView adding subview problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have a UITableView which have many row in a section. when i scroll down to the bottom row, and click a button to add a subview, my subview will display at the bottom on the screen rather than from top,can anyone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clarify your question:

Are you asking about adding a row to the UITableView or a sub-view to the UITableRow? If you want to add a new row, you'll need to insert a row, update your dataSource and reload the table.

You cannot and should not add a sub-view to the UITableView. It doesn't work that way.

Look at the documentation:

[UITableView Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)